# How to deserialize the following file using C# XML Serialization where the root itself is the IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization

```
<results>
    <result>
        <egov_ref_no>20121203001</egov_ref_no>
        <status>OK</status>
        <err_code>01</err_code>
    </result>
    <result>
        <egov_ref_no>20121203002</egov_ref_no>
        <status>OK</status>
        <err_code>02</err_code>
    </result>
    <result>
        <egov_ref_no>20121203003</egov_ref_no>
        <status>OK</status>
        <err_code>03</err_code>
    </result>
</results>
```

The code above shows that the root node is already an IEnumerable where as in online examples they are only elements.

Comment: Could you post a code? How do you try to deserialize it?

Comment: Do you have a `result` object or do you just want anonymous types

Comment: Yes, I have a 'result' object but what i need is the list of the 'result' object. Thanks.

Comment: was [this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/36695/1396) your question? If so, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a results object you can just pass in a `XmlRootAttribute` into the `XmlSerializer` constructor. In this case its "results"

Example:

```
List<Result> results = new List<Result>();

XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Result>), new XmlRootAttribute("results"));

using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"C:\Test.xml", FileMode.Open))
{
    results = (List<Result>)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(stream);
}
```

My result object:

```
[XmlType(TypeName = "result")]
public class Result
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "egov_ref_no")]
    public long EgovRefNo { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "err_code")]
    public int ErrorCode { get; set; }
}
```

This will return as `List<Result>`

[image]

Comment: Many thanks sa_ddam and  Andrey Gordeev. My problem is solved.